# CORS Proxy with PHP Curl (but with Client IP)

Tags: php, curl, proxy, cors

В общем есть некое API, где выдаётся ссылка привязанная к IP адресу клиента.
Я попытался запросить с сайта через `XmlHttpRequest` и через `fetch`.
Но CORS блокирует такое соединение, тк сервер не передаёт разрешающие заголовки.
Пробовал сунуть в `iframe`. Дак там нельзя получить внутренний контент из-за CORS
Пробовал плагин `Cors Unblock`. Сработало. Но не один нормальный человек не будет устанавливать себе непонятные плагины, чтобы посидеть на сайте.
В общем созрела идея сделать просто прокси.

А проблема вот в чём.
Не могу передать фейковый IP (IP клиента), конечному серверу, где сидит API.
В любом случае улетает адрес моего сервера.

Пробовал с PHP curl передать такие заголовки `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [  "REMOTE_ADDR: $ipAddress",  "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ipAddress",  "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR: $ipAddress",  "HTTP_X_FORWARDED: $ipAddress",  "HTTP_FORWARDED: $ipAddress",  "HTTP_CLIENT_IP: $ipAddress",  "HTTP_X_CLIENT_IP: $ipAddress",  "HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP: $ipAddress",  "HTTP_X_REAL_IP: $ipAddress",  "HTTP_REAL_IP: $ipAddress"]);`

И ничего не сработало.
Может вы знаете, как ещё можно решить такую проблему?

Comment: А зачем вам отправлять чужой IP ? Если это нужно, то настраивать нужно прокси в curl. Там, конечно, будет не клиентский, но и не вашего сервера

Comment: Так как ссылка привязывается к IP клиента, то получить её может только сам клиент. А если делать запрос с сервера то и ссылка привяжется к IP сервера